# How can I make HOC/Middleware in Node to measure time exec?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have something like:

`router.get("/", users)`

```
const users = (req, res) => {
  const begin = new Date().getTime()

  // rest of the code

  const end = new Date().getTime()
  const duration = (begin - end) / 1000

  res.send("something")
}
```

So I don't want to repeat my self each time in every route like this, is there a way to make HOC/middleware to handle this? I tried several things, but can't get my head around how to make it.

Comment: So something like [express' "response-time"](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/response-time.html) ?

Comment: @Seblor I guess so, didn't hear about "response-time" package, thank you. Is this possible to create without the package and its dependencies like "on-headers" etc? Just to see how this can be done without a package to learn the process.

Comment: Also, doesn't this package breaks the "next()" functionality of the routes? I see it has the following code(with "time" instead of "next" param): 
`onHeaders(res, function onHeaders () {
      var diff = process.hrtime(startAt)
      var time = diff[0] * 1e3 + diff[1] * 1e-6

      fn(req, res, time)
    })`